# Why does my shaded pole motor barely rotate when driven at 1/2 its rated voltage?

Tags: induction-motor, rpm

Hello electronics community!

I'm attempting to service a shaded pole motor (pictured below) that is used for rotating a cylindrical fan from an electrical heater.  The fan stopped rotating and so I thought I'd take it apart to see if I could figure out what's wrong with it.

After cleaning the unit and lubricating the bearings with dielectric silicone grease, I ran the motor from the mains at 120V (I don't have a safe test rig to run at 240V).  I expected it to run at half a reasonable RPM as the motor generally operates at 240V when in the heater assembly.  Unfortunately it barely rotates (maybe 60 RPM at best), and with the weight of the fan, I doubt it would move at all.

Is this expected when operating one of these motors at a lower-rated voltage?  What other test can I perform to verify the integrity of the motor?

Incidentally, the bushings that attach to the rotor don't easily rotate; they do pivot easily though.  I believe is intentional since they are supposed to stabilize the rotor's axis of rotation, and not grip the axle and rotate with it.  Several videos and articles suggest saturating the bushing with a lubricant, which I've done, so that doesn't appear to be the problem.

Finally, I tested for continuity on the primary coil and read a resistance of about 150Ω, which is about right as the label on the coil gives a current rating of 1.3A (240V/150Ω = 1.8A).

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to proceed testing are appreciated!

[image: 240V, 1.8A Shaded Pole Motor, less one bushing]

Comment: "*I expected it to run at half a reasonable RPM*", you halved the voltage, not the frequency.

Comment: Thank you @HarrySvensson for that insight!  After a bit of research, I should reach 3600rpm for an ideal motor with two poles (as above) on 60Hz AC.  How does the voltage factor into the operation of the motor?  I suppose if is too low, it will not generate a strong-enough magnetic field to drive the rotor.

Comment: the bushings should not spin ..... if they start spinning, then there is a problem ...... some bushings are sintered, which means that they are porous and will absorb oil for self-lubrication purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the motor running to a proper RPM again by using a proper lubricant!  Too much friction on the axle was preventing rotation.

The original silicone grease that I used was too viscous and is typically used for automotive work (brake calipers).  It wasn't binding to the bushings properly, so the friction on the rotating axles was hardly reduced.  After applying the liquid lubricant, I could freely rotate the fan on the axle and watch it spin for several seconds.

I found a switched 240 outlet that I could use for testing, and verified that the motor spins properly under normal power.

Answer (score 2):

The RPM at constant torque is (more or less) proportional to voltage on a shaded pole motor **with a fan load**, which is why simple triac speed controls work fairly well (again, with a fan load only).

(Image from [this](https://shareok.org/bitstream/handle/11244/43418/Thesis-1951-H122p.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) Masters Thesis.

[image]

Figure B represents the fan load as a function of RPM

Figure C represents the transfer function of the motor-fan system at different voltages.

As far as the motor characteristics with **non* fan loads go, here is what they look like (from *Standard Handbook for Electrical Engineers, 8th Edition (1949)*)

[image]

The mass of the fan is not so significant, the friction is important. Starting torque on shaded pole motors is low, as Tony says, and as you can see from the above curves, it's less than 50% of maximum torque, a stark contrast to many motor designs which have a much higher starting torque than running torque.

You should be able to test it. Since you're in the US you can get 240V fairly easily from a dryer outlet etc., sometimes even from multiple 120V outlets.

If the motor shaft turns completely freely (if you spin it, it doesn't immediately come to a stop but at least turns a few times around) it's probably okay. If it binds, probably better to buy a new motor.

Answer (score 1):

The phase angle between the shaded and unshaded sections is small, so shaded-pole motors have a small starting torque relative to full speed.

Even if the rotor seems smooth, at 50% voltage it may be normal to have insuffient torque.